# add class to a table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting

```
this.parentNode = '<tr><td>One</td>' +
                  '<td>Two</td>' +
                  '<td>Three</td>' +
                  '</tr>';
```

Now, I need to add a class to the `<tr>`.

In a normal scenario, I can just do `$('#tableId tr').addClass('classname');`

However, in this case I have the html inside this.parentNode. How can I add the classname to the `<tr>` here?

Comment: why can't you just modify the string to add the class

Comment: Can you please explain? . I need to add the class and I have this.parentNode. It does not have a method addClass like in jQuery

Comment: I think what Arun might be getting at is doing <tr class="classname"><td>One</td>. If you have the markup string in your Javascript, you can add the class directly, instead of adding the class programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do 2 things:

This,

```
this.parentNode = '<tr class="className"><td>One</td>' +
                  '<td>Two</td>' +
                  '<td>Three</td>' +
                  '</tr>';
```

Or this,

Define the this.parentNode just like how you did, and then do this :

```
    $(this.parentNode).addClass("className")
```

This adds the class to the tr tag in the parentNode.